# Выравнивание по правому краю одного из TextView в Layout

Tags: android, textview

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь выравнять одно поле tvGroupDate по правому краю экрана, но оно прилипло слева и не хочет двигаться, помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llGroup">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
                android:minLines="1"
                android:maxLines="160"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Group name"
                android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Date"
                android:id="@+id/tvGroupDate"
                android:password="false"
                android:phoneNumber="false"
                android:editable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

На экране это выглядит так:
[image]

На стековерфлоу нашел пару ответов, но они не помогли. там писали установить 
`android:layout_width="fill_parent"` и `android:layout_gravity="right"`, но как видно из xml, параметры стоят, а поле не двинулось вправо...
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если уж используете веса, то и назначьте `tvGroupDate` `android:layout_width="0dp"` и `android:layout_weight="2"`.

Comment: На самом деле непонятно, что хотите в итоге получить? Два текствью по краям? Или первый вообще не нужен? Попробуйте пояснить.

Comment: @jimpanzer - да, два текстовых по краям. Решил на данный момент задачу при помощи RelativeLayout, но хотелось бы узнать как решить её при помощи Linear

Comment: я отредактировал ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте лучше для этих целей Relative Layout.  
В нем можно указать, относительно чего выровнять конкретный View

Или попробуйте изменить layout_gravity на gravity

**UPD**  
Проверил у себя. Ваш внутренний LinearLayout имеет ширину

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

И соответственно, не заполняет весь экран по ширине.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="160"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:text="Group name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvGroupDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:password="false"
            android:phoneNumber="false"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Графический редактор не такая уж и бесполезная штука, как видите...